# Cannot create tag synonym with number although it does not contain a version

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I tried to suggest the existing tag [s4sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4sdk) as a tag synonym for [sap-cloud-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-cloud-sdk).

The rationale is that "s4sdk" refers the the "SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK", which has been [broadened in scope by SAP](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/05/06/sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-transforms-into-sap-cloud-sdk/) to the generic "SAP Cloud SDK".
That is, there is not longer any use for "s4sdk", and this tag could either be merged into the "sap-cloud-sdk" while keeping all currently tagged questions or at least have a synonym so that people start using "sap-cloud-sdk".

Although I have create "tag synonyms privilege" I run into the following error:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

It sounds to me like the s4 in s4sdk is considered as version number. Actually it stands for the product name "SAP S/4HANA". Am I missing something?

Comment: The heuristic for when a tag is version-specific is fairly limited. I've retagged your question to a synonym request, because letting the mods handle the rare edge-cases when it fails is fine imo.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me... so I've created the syn. If someone has a reason it shouldn't be that I'm missing... just comment here...